# Are there any materials with no use that can always be sold?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Are all materials used at some point or are there some I can sell without much thought?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All materials in Breath of the Wild can be used in some capacity.

Most are used in potions or food. In some cases, such as Gems, they are also used in upgrading armor.

There is in theory nothing that can be freely sold, but as you'll play you'll figure out what things you do use and what you don't (for example, if you always use Hotfoot Lizards to make Fireproof Elixers then you can sell the other materials that make Fireproof Elixers).

Comment: From what I also found, diamonds are something that can be sold, but should be kept for use.  Just remember, *diamonds are a Links best friend.*

Comment: @TimmyJim Diamonds are used for upgrading some armour sets and for re-forging certain weapons.

Answer (score -1):

You can sell 10 sapphires to a Gerudo woman who walks around in Goron city during daytime, She gives you 2900 instead of 2600. Minor increase but it helps in the long run!

Comment: Do sapphires not have any other use?

Comment: Saphires are used in some Recipies so this answer is invalid for this Question.

Comment: You can sell ANY gem to her, it changes everyday, though it never changed for me except when I sell the gems. It always sells for 300 more than normal shops.